# 2 ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

```
I want to display the result of a search in a listView and separate the result with titles.
My Solution is that I use 2 listView with headerView for each one and display them 
but this is what I get:
```

[click here to see the picture](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/831073Sanstitre.png)

```
I thought I can put them into a scrollView but I'v searched for a solution and it seems that I can't.
So what should I do to make a scrollbar for all the activity ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one `ListView` and no `ScrollView`. Have the `ListAdapter` for the `ListView` handle the entire result set, including the headings. There are various libraries to help with this, such [my CWAC-Merge library with its `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

Comment: it's complicated a little bit XD